# error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’

Tags: c++, templates

I'm a C++ newbie. I want to determine the size of string array in C++. Following advice on this forum, I've created a template to give me the size of the array. The releavant code is

```
virtual std::string _verify_list_or_string(std::string obj[]) {     
    std::cout << "debug " << sizeof_array(std::string, sizeof(obj)) << std::endl;
```

The template I'm using is

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
std::size_t sizeof_array( T (&)[N] ) {
   return N;
}
```

I get a compile error: "error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that, despite the `[]`, the function argument is a pointer and not an array. You can only pass an array to a function by reference, and then it must be a reference to a specific size of array - the size is part of the array's type.

If you need the size of an array that's been passed as a pointer, then some options are:

- make the function itself a template, like your `sizeof_array`, so that the array is passed by reference and the size available as a template parameter;
- make the function a template taking an iterator range in two arguments, so it can be used with any kind of sequence (including arrays);
- pass the size of the array as a second argument;
- pass a class type like `std::array` or `std::vector` with an interface that can give you the size.

The error is because you're passing nonsense to `sizeof_array`. If `obj` were an array, then you'd do `sizeof_array(obj)`, and the template arguments would be inferred from the type of `obj`. But it isn't an array, so that won't work either.

Answer (score 2):

Your function takes one parameter:

```
std::size_t sizeof_array( T (&)[N] )
//                       ^^^^^^^^^^
```

But you're passing two. Moreover, one of them - type:

```
sizeof_array(std::string, sizeof(obj))
//           ^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You'd probably want to pass an `obj` variable. But the problem is that `obj` is not an array here. So, you can't get size of `obj` this way.

Answer (score 2):

The problematic expression is `sizeof_array(std::string, sizeof(obj))`: `std::string` isn't an expression but a type. Fixing that expression won't help, though: the argument `obj` isn't a suitable argument for `sizeof_array()` because it has type `std::string*` while `sizeof_array()` takes an array reference as argument.

Once the array has decayed into a pointer there is no way to recover the array size. If you want to automatically determine the size of an array in a function, you need to pass the array by reference, e.g.:

```
template <int Size>
std::string _verify_list_or_string(std::string (&obj)[Size]) {
    std::cout << "debug " << sizeof_array(obj) << '\n';
    return _verify_list_or_string(obj, Size);
}
virtual std::string _verify_list_or_string(std::string* obj, int Size) {
    ...
}
```

Note that the primary entry point was turned into a template which can't be `virtual`. Thus, it forwards to a `virtual` function taking a pointer to the array and its size.

Comment: Of course, this makes the call to `sizeof_array` utterly useless.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I'm not disagreeing. I left the call to `sizeof_array()` to show that the `obj` can now be passed to this function (I used `Size` directly when delegating).

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you invoke a template function... arguments, not template parameters go inside the function-call parentheses.  That function is designed to infer the template parameters.  If inference wasn't possible, you'd call like this:

```
std::string ary[6];
sizeof_array<std::string, 6>(ary);
```

Since inference is possible, the compiler will figure out the template parameters if you just pass the argument:

```
sizeof_array(ary);
```

Unfortunately for you, that template function only works on arrays, but you have a pointer.  There's no size information for you to get to.